# DBeaver - missing procedures in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, settings, procedure, dbeaver

I have connected to my work database via DBeaver. Recently colleague told me about a procedure that lets me check newly added entities through our front-end.
And I can't find it in the list of procedures, nor using this query:
`SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Name LIKE '%name%'`

I have the same connection settings as my colleague's, same user, etc, but he uses DbForge and I use DBeaver, cause at some point of time DbForge began having too much restrictions for free version (I wasn't simply able to execute queries), and the older version my colleague gave me didn't install in Windows 11.

So, I'm thinking may be there's some settings in the DBeaver that hide certain stored procedures, or I need to adjust connection settings.

Does anyone has clue on this?

Or may be someone could suggest some alternative to DbForge, which allows to execute queries in the free version and to set colors to connections (I find that thing convenient), and possibly doesn't have this problem, may be because of being more MySQl-oriented.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried to open connection settings and check out the additional parameters there, but can't seem to notice anything relevant.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised that a mysql client would only hide certain stored procedures, but not others. But to clarify if it is a client issue, install mysql workbench and see if you can find the missing stored proc.

Comment: Case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like there was misunderstanding between me and my colleague, and he actually meant some another DB Server, but with same User/Password combination. Thanks for the comments, that also helped in finding the cause. I really did install MySQL Workbench, saw the same picture in there, and started wondering what else it could be and reading our communication again.

My mistake) The question is no longer actual.